# How to show an Info mode manual entirely on one page

Tags: info

Using `C-h R elisp` brings up the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual in Info mode.

How can I show the manual entirely on one page?

Something akin to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html?

Comment: What do you mean by “entirely on one page”?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, and I don't see the benefit. Perhaps you could share what you're trying to do.

Comment: @db48x exactly as described on this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html; not sure how I can be any more descriptive

Comment: @aadcg Having the entire manual on one page would let my _swiper_ through the document https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper

Comment: Opening up a *.info file and manually and evaluating `Info-fontify-node` is almost what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm not saying I have any trouble using `swiper` in the document as raw text itself, but it would certainly be nice to be able to use `swiper` (or `isearch`) on the *entire* Info-mode-modified-document with all the benefits of Info mode (i.e., clicking on links, etc.)

Comment: @JohnDeBord that's exactly what I thought. Swiper won't be of any help here. You need tools to search info manuals that are provided by `info` itself! Take a look at the following commands: `Info-search` (bound to `s`) and `info-apropos`. Take the opportunity to read the info manual that teaches you how to use info :) `M-x Info-help`; evaluate `(info "(info) Advanced")`.

Comment: Ok, so you don’t want it to be squashed down so that the whole section you are viewing is visible without scrolling. You just don’t know how to access other chapters of the book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use [Info+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus) then you can easily get a whole manual, or any node together with its subnodes, in a single, fully functional Info buffer.

Command **`Info-merge-subnodes`**, bound to **`+`** in `Info-mode`, integrates the current Info node with
its subnodes (the nodes in its Menu), perhaps recursively.
Use it to extract a self-contained report (possibly the whole manual) from an Info manual.  The report is itself an Info buffer, with hyperlinks and normal Info behavior.

There are various prefix-argument possibilities that govern
just how subnodes are treated (recursively or not, for
instance).  There are a few user options that let you
customize the report appearance.  Here's what `C-h k +` tells you:

> **`+`** runs the command **`Info-merge-subnodes`** (found in `Info-mode-map`), which
> is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [**`info+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/info%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `+`, `menu-bar Info Merge Subnodes`.
>
> `(Info-merge-subnodes &optional RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P RECURSIVE-CALL-P)`
>
> Integrate current node with nodes referred to in its Menu.
>
> Displays the current Info node, together with the nodes in its Menu.
> Buffer `*Info: NODE*` is used for the display, where `NODE` is the name
> of the current node.  The contents of this node's subnodes (the nodes
> named in this node's Menu) are included in the buffer, following the
> contents of the current node.
>
> Optional arg `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` (prefix arg if interactive) governs
> the way menus of subnodes are treated:
>
> - If `nil`, nothing additional happens.  Subnode menus are not explored.
>   Only the current node and its immediate subnodes are documented, in
>   the single display buffer `*Info: NODE*`.
> - If non-`nil`, then the subnodes of a node are treated in the same way
>   as the parent node, recursively: If any of them has, itself, a Menu,
>   then that menu's subnodes are also explored, and so on.
>
>   - If `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` is zero, then a single display buffer is
>     used for all of the nodes explored.  Otherwise, a separate display
>     buffer is used for each subnode that has a Menu (see next).
>
>     Use this when you want a single, flat compilation of the current
>     node and all of its subnodes.  It is less appropriate when the
>     current node has several levels of subnodes: The flattened
>     result can be difficult to read.
>   - If `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` is positive, then the contents of each
>     subnode are displayed twice: once in the parent node's display,
>     and once in the subnode's own display.
>
>     Use this when the current node has several levels of subnodes
>     and you want each display buffer to be self-contained.
>   - If `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` is negative, then there is no redundancy: A
>     subnode's contents are only displayed in its parent's buffer.  The
>     subnode's own display buffer only contains the contents of its own
>     subnodes.
>
>     Use this when the current node has several levels of subnodes
>     and you want no redundancy between the display buffers.
>
> The user option (variable) `Info-subtree-separator` is a string to be
> inserted by `Info-merge-subnodes` just before the title of each
> node (preceding its description).  By default it is `"\n* "`, producing
> a node title resembling a menu item.  Setting this to `"\f\n* "` will
> cause a page break before each node description.  For more on setting
> this variable, type `C-h v Info-subtree-separator`.
>
> ---
>
> Optional second arg `RECURSIVE-CALL-P` is only for internal use.  It is
> used to indicate whether (non-`nil`) or not (`nil`) this is a recursive
> (i.e. not a top-level) call to `Info-merge-subnodes`.  Non-`nil`
> means that this is a subnode, and that its contents should only be
> included in the present display if `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` is also
> non-`nil`.  For proper operation when `RECURSIVE-DISPLAY-P` is zero, the
> non-`nil` value of `RECURSIVE-CALL-P` should be the node name of the
> top-level call to `Info-merge-subnodes`.

Comment: Wasn't aware this package existed; thanks!

Comment: Been using it for years, didn't know (or forgot) that it could do this. Thanks as always Drew.

Comment: @PhilHudson: It was actually the first thing I did - the initial reason for creating `info+.el`, back in 1996! It's hardly changed since then - see the Change log in the file.

Answer (score 5):

The info buffers already contain the whole manual. They just use narrowing to show one section at a time.

If you want to see the whole thing, just do `C-x n w` to widen the buffer.

No need for packages.

EDIT: Since Info-mode re-narrows the buffer when following links, one can use an advice to keep the buffer wide:

```
(defun widen-after-info-follow (&rest _)
  (widen))

(advice-add 'Info-follow-nearest-node :after 'widen-after-info-follow)
```

Comment: Is there a way to also get all of the links to work as well?

Comment: @JohnDeBord Yeah. I've edited the answer to show how one can keep the buffer wide when following links.